# SetInterval only run for first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learning javascript, react, and i tried to count from 10 to 0, but somehow the timer only run to 9, i thought setInterval run every n time we set (n can be 1000ms, 2000ms...)

Here is the code

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  const startCountDown = () => {
    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time - 1);
    }, 1000);
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startCountDown();
        }}
      >
        Start countdown
      </button>
      <div>{time}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/class-component-ujc9s?file=/src/App.tsx:0-506

Please explain for this, i'm so confuse, thank you

Comment: You should move `clearInterval(countdown);` inside `setInterval`. Also on each click you trigger **new** setInterval while `time` stays global for all events

Comment: Try using `setTime(time => time - 1);` as well?

Comment: @Andreas `setTime` changes `time`

Comment: @evolutionxbox it work !! but howwwww? and it not stop at 0 , swear i don't know why it work, what make this different

Comment: Move the if statement inside the setTime callback function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sadly it not work

Comment: Then consider using [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and a `setTimeout`? You should not be checking state right after it's set. [Like this](https://gist.github.com/bbachi/73afd46e3ac356866b41c192138644b5#file-countdowntimer-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use callback in your setState function because otherwise react is working with old value of time:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  const startCountDown = () => {
    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevTime)=>prevTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startCountDown();
        }}
      >
        Start countdown
      </button>
      <div>{time}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

edit: You can store your interval identificator in useRef, because useRef persist through rerender and it will not cause another rerender, and then check for time in `useEffect` with `time` in dependency

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);
  const interval = useRef(0);
  const startCountDown = () => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 1);
    }, 1000);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    }
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startCountDown();
        }}
      >
        Start countdown
      </button>
      <div>{time}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/class-component-forked-lgiyj?file=/src/App.tsx:0-613

Comment: thank for your answer, but somehow it not stop at 0

Comment: check pleas edit of this answer :)

Comment: i mark as answer, thank for your answer, but i have another question, that if i use useState, will it possible to make countdown work? It would be great if you help me this, thank you, i'm trying to understand react

Comment: if you mean instead of useRef, it should but it will cause unecessary rerender

Comment: thank for your answer, but if i useState, how can i do that, feel like useEffect even not work, i put clearIntervel in useEffect but it still not stop, why this happen? Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/class-component-ujc9s?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: you need to keep `countdown` in useState, because everything what is not in useState nor useRef will be redeclared each render

Answer (score 5):

`time` is the value read from the state (which is the default passed passed into `useState`) each time the component renders.

When you click, you call `setInterval` with a function that closes over the `time` that came from the last render

Every time the component is rendered from then on, it reads a new value of `time` from the state.

The interval is still working with the **original** variable though, which is still `10`.

---

State functions will give you the current value of the state if you pass in a callback. So use that instead of the closed over variable.

```
setTime(currentTime => currentTime - 1);
```

Comment: Each render also creates a new interval, causing the countdown to jump.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — No, only clicks do that.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for your answer, but somehow i still can't find out why it not stop at 0

Comment: My question is, when we use setState(newState) and when to use setState((state)=>{newState})

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you call `setTime` multiple times (yourselves or in a `setIntervall`) React will wait before picking the last one. To avoid this, you should pass a function updater to set your state:

```js
 const coutRef = useRef();

 const startCountDown = () => {
    coutRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time => time - 1);
    }, 1000);
 };

 useEffect(()=>{
   if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(coutRef.current);
    }
 },[time])
```